# What is the best practice for metaclass methods that call each other?

Tags: python, metaclass, pylint

I'm trying to build a metaclass, and I was just thinking I was really getting it. And I want to have class methods for each of the instances of this metaclass.

```
class MyMeta(type):
    """A metaclass"""
    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, attributes):
        pass

    def _foo(cls):
        pass

    def _bar(cls):
        cls._foo()
```

When I run pylint on it, the `cls._foo` has difficulty:

```
[pylint] E1120:No value for argument 'cls' in unbound method call
```

When I try running the code (My code is more complex than this) it appears to be running fine, and doing what I'm expecting it to do. So how am I supposed to fix this case? What does it mean precisely.

It sounds like other errors related to not properly declaring things as `@staticmethods`, but I can't mark this as a `@classmethod` because then it would be a Metaclass method.

Related searches seem to be talking about places where people are dynamically adding constructors or something, and I don't think this is that case. Am I misunderstanding something still about metaclasses?

What I really want is class methods that call each other defined in a metaclass. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35208443/pylint-complains-no-value-for-argument-cls

Comment: @SteveJ That's specifically the case I mentioned. The OP in that question  is expecting a constructor to be declared in a derived class. This isn't the case here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [pylint] E1120:No value for argument 'cls' in unbound method call

As far as your metaclasss is concerned, your `_foo` and `_bar` methods are just ordinary Python methods - which means Python will fill in a reference to each class (metaclass instance) automatically when calling these methods.

And, as this is a metaclass, for clarity, semantics, and readability, it is much better to do as you did: name their first parameter as `cls` instead of `self`.

The problem is just that pylint does not knw about that: it is likely it is expecting a hard-coded `self`. 
Your code, in this respect is irretouchable.

All you have to do is to add a meta-comment fo that pylint ignore these lines - fortunatelly, Pylint allows it at block level, unlike some tools where you have to mark that in each line.

```
class MyMeta(type):
    """A metaclass"""
    # pylint: disable=no-value-for-parameter

    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, attributes):
        pass

    def _foo(cls):
        pass

    def _bar(cls):
        cls._foo()
```

Your example metaclass, with the "meta-comment" so that pylint ignores your non-error.

Comment: +1, This makes a lot of sense. but I think what your answer amounts to is, "I think this is a bug/limitation in pylint, just disable it." Not to say I think you're wrong, but there's nothing here that is authoritative.

Comment: I've edited the title of the question for a little more clarity.

Comment: That won't change my answer. There is a part there reading "... it is much better to do how you did".

You just have to be aware that these methods in the metaclass won't be visible in the instances of your classes: they are class methods only. (That is sometimes an advantage, and a design, I'd wish Python's `datetime.datetime` had taken)

Comment: "Not visible in the instances" Is a desirable feature.