# Pylint yelling about cls parameter in meta class

Tags: python, metaclass, pylint

First time I'm writing a meta class here. It's on the simple side because I need it for a specific case, but here goes.

Pylint throws this error `no-value-for-parameter / No value for argument 'cls' in unbound method call` specifically on the lines commented below.

Here is my code

```
class ContractType(type):
    _instance = None
    _contract_interface = None

    def create_contract_interface(cls):
        contract_json = open(str(settings.CONTRACT_DIR + cls.token_name)).read()
        cls._contract_interface = json.loads(contract_json)
        return cls._contract_interface

    def create_instance(cls):
        cls._instance = w3.eth.contract(abi=cls._contract_interface['abi'], bytecode=cls._contract_interface['bytecode'])
        return cls._instance

    def __getattr__(cls, key):
        if not cls._contract_interface:  # This line is failing pylint
            cls.create_contract_interface()
        if not cls._instance:  # This line is failing pylint
            cls.create_instance()
        if key == "contract_interface":
            return cls._contract_interface
        return getattr(cls._instance, key, None)


class Tempo(metaclass=ContractType):
    token_name = 'TempoToken.json'
```

Any idea why pylint is throwing this error? The code works as expected. I found this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35208443/pylint-complains-no-value-for-argument-cls) but it's not exactly my situation.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the "errors" are on the next lines (calling `create_contract_interface` and `create_instance`). It still seems like a false-positive to me.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pylint error - the code above is correct. The porblem is that while in writting metaclass code it makes all sense to replace the conventional `self` first parameter with `cls`, pylint has the `self` name hard-coded, and can't "see" the called methods use `cls` instead of `self` as the name for their automatic parameter. If it were `self` then it would "know" no parameter was needed.

My suggestion is just to add a `# noQA` comment to the lines calling `cls.create_contract_interface()` and `cls.create_instance()` and move on -

Remember> linters should be helpers, but since they can't know about all the possibilities in dynamic languages such as Python, in this case the linter is hindering you.