# Pylance showing error for @classmethod which works during execution

Tags: python, pylance

The following code works exactly as expected:

```
from abc import ABCMeta

from typing import Dict, Any

class Singleton(ABCMeta):
    __instances: Dict[Any, Any] = {}
    def __call__(cls, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> Any:
        if cls not in cls.__instances:
            cls.__instances[cls] = super(Singleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls.__instances[cls]

    @classmethod
    def delete_all_instances(cls: Any) -> None:
        cls.__instances = {}
        print("Deleted")

class Class1(metaclass=Singleton):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        print("Constructor")
        self.__name = 'Class1'

    def say_name(self) -> str:
        return self.__name


if __name__ == "__main__":
    obj1 = Class1()
    print(obj1.say_name())
    Singleton.delete_all_instances()
    obj1 = Class1()
    print(obj1.say_name())
```

Output:

```
Constructor
Class1
Deleted
Constructor
Class1
```

But Pylance (v2023.5.10) installed in Visual Studio Code 1.78.0 complains in line 29 `Singleton.delete_all_instances()`, that `Argument missing for parameter "cls"`. It doesn't matter, if the `Any` behind the cls-parameter in the function definition is there, or not.
Is this a bug in Pylance, or am I just too blind to see the issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/35208904/7169710

Comment: @PietroD'Antuono: Nope, this was a different issue. This was a real bug in Pyright - see my answer and the linked Github issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a real bug in Pyright. See [bug report on Github](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/issues/5079)